# Ubuntu 13.04 on Alienware M17x R5

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers

I've got an M17X-R5 with the Intel 4800 cpu, Nvidia 3d graphics and it came with 5g wifi and a killer ethernet card. This is to replace my ageing M17x R1 which until recently worked perfectly with all I threw at it from Ubnutu 10.04 onwards.

When I come to install Ubuntu 13.04 on the new Alienware, all appears well except it doesn't detect an internet connection to download the updates whist it installs.  I've tried with a physical cable, via wifi and can only get it to detect a wireless connection if I plug in an old USB wifi adapter.

After installing with the USB wifi plugged in, and all patches applied, it still refuses point blank to detect a network unless I use the USB adapter.  I've tried installing Jockey and looking for additional drivers/hardware but none are found.

I'm very comfortable with Unix/Linux/AIX etc, but have to admit that when it comes to drivers and Linux, I'm a novice.  Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
In answer to PJ Singh's very pertinent question in the comment section, this is a snip from the lspci command taken at boot from a USB boot disk (Try Ubuntu option) without any external wifi dongles installed:

```
08:00.0 Ethernet Controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2200 Gigiabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
0a:00.0 Network Controller: Broadcom Corporation Device 43b1 (rev 03)
```

I should also note that when I said to begin with that it couldn't find any wifi networks  to install the updates over, it actually couldn't find any wireless adapters.

Edit:

Added output from process here (nicer formatting)

```
root@m17xr5-lnx:/usr/src/b43b1-6.30.223.95# lsmod | grep wl
wl                   4117081  0 
lib80211               14352  2 wl,lib80211_crypt_tkip
cfg80211              510937  3 wl,mac80211,rt2x00lib
root@m17xr5-lnx:/usr/src/b43b1-6.30.223.95# cat /etc/modules 
wl
root@m17xr5-lnx:/usr/src/b43b1-6.30.223.95#
```

Edit:

Resolved this today (September 29th 2013) by installing the latest Broadcomm drivers that are available with 13.10.  No compilation required, just installed using the package manager and loh-and-behold, the wireless adapter came to life - didn't even need a reboot.

Comment: Without the USB wireless device plugged in, does $ lspci list your physical network hardware?

Comment: Yes, it lists: 08:00.0 Ethernet Controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2200 Gigiabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10) & 0a:00.0 Network Controller: Broadcom Corporation Device 43b1 (rev 03).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for your Broadcom Corporation 43b1 wireless device...

```
$ sudo apt-get --yes install linux-headers-generic debhelper fakeroot build-essential dkms
$ cd ~/Downloads
$ wget http://people.canonical.com/~ypwong/drivers/broadcom/hybrid-v35_64-nodebug-pcoem-6_30_223_95.tar.gz
$ mkdir b43b1-6.30.223.95
$ tar xvzf hybrid-v35_64-nodebug-pcoem-6_30_223_95.tar.gz -C b43b1-6.30.223.95
$ echo -e 'PACKAGE_NAME="b43b1"\nPACKAGE_VERSION="6.30.223.95"\nCLEAN="make clean"\nMAKE="make"\nBUILT_MODULE_NAME="wl"\nBUILT_MODULE_LOCATION="./"\nDEST_MODULE_LOCATION="/updates"\n' > ./b43b1-6.30.223.95/dkms.conf
$ cat b43b1-6.30.223.95/dkms.conf
$ sudo mv b43b1-6.30.223.95 /usr/src/b43b1-6.30.223.95
$ sudo chown -R root:root /usr/src/b43b1-6.30.223.95/
$ cd /usr/src/b43b1-6.30.223.95
$ sudo dkms add -m b43b1 -v 6.30.223.95
$ sudo dkms build -m b43b1 -v 6.30.223.95
$ sudo rmmod wl
```

If you get, "`Error: Module wl is in use`," just ignore it.

```
$ sudo dkms install -m b43b1 -v 6.30.223.95
$ sudo modprobe wl
```

Then reboot.
(Press `<CTRL>-C` if `modprobe` hangs; in that case you will have to use your power button to shut down, but the module should load automatically once you restart; see below if it doesn't).

Log back in and make sure that the `wl` module was loaded:

```
$ lsmod | grep wl
```

You should not need to do the following, but if the `wl` module is not loaded after rebooting, type this and reboot again.

```
$ echo 'wl' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

*Note: This solution was adapted from psyray's posting on bug [14e4:43b1 Broadcom Corporation Device 43b1 (rev 03) - not supported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1173761).  You can reference that bug for more information.*

Comment: Hi, I'll be able to test this shortly.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: OK.  I just retested this on a fresh install and I added a couple of comments about the error you can ignore and what to do if modprobe hangs.  Note that the 6th line (the echo command) is pretty long, so make sure you cut and paste the whole line.

Comment: I've tried the above line by line however I get Network Manager telling me there are no network adapters available. I encountered no errors through the process. I'll re-run after a rebuild, just in case.

Comment: That's disappointing.  You definitely have the Broadcom 43b1 chip, per your lspci output.  If you haven't checked it already, make sure System Settings | Network | Wireless is set to "On".

Comment: root@m17xr5-lnx:/usr/src/b43b1-6.30.223.95# lsmod | grep wl
wl                   4117081  0 
lib80211               14352  2 wl,lib80211_crypt_tkip
cfg80211              510937  3 wl,mac80211,rt2x00lib
root@m17xr5-lnx:/usr/src/b43b1-6.30.223.95# cat /etc/modules 
wl
root@m17xr5-lnx:/usr/src/b43b1-6.30.223.95# 
This is what I have, but unfortunately, still no joy.

Comment: Your network adepter seems to have both an Ethernet AND wireless chip built into a single device.  Just a shot in the dark, but have you tried turning off the wired network?  May be it can't use both at the same time?